# Could not read document: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status CLOSED

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I'm using SpringMVC to get json data. I get the error sometimes. Is the network closed or our server has something wrong. How to fix it?

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at com.expedia.www.epc.photos.v2.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:65)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at com.yammer.metrics.web.WebappMetricsFilter.doFilter(WebappMetricsFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.read(SecureNioChannel.java:474)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:173)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:250)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:231)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:133)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:476)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:350)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:375)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:204)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._loadMoreGuaranteed(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2404)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2579)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1010)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:364)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2922)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:222)
    ... 49 more